# Combo Box, Fixed Item Header

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a listview with a dataview view:

```
 <ListView Name="ListView_DataQuery" SelectionChanged="ListView_DataQuery_SelectionChanged">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>

            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ComputerName}">
                <ComboBox Name="Column1" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" MaxDropDownHeight="800"  Text="Machine Name"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding Filter_ListView_DataQuery}" 
                          AllowDrop="False" IsEditable="True" IsManipulationEnabled="False" IsReadOnly="True" Focusable="False"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding MachineNames}" ForceCursor="True">
                </ComboBox>
            </GridViewColumn>
```

Bindings are all working, im filtering and everything looks good enough.
Problem is that i would like drop down headers for all my columns, i have massaged this combo box to the state where, the combobox header displays a text on userform load. the text in this box is not editable or selectable.

issues i have left over which i cant seem to figure out.
When i put my cursor over the text it shows the TextEdit cursor "the I looking one" and the next issue is that when you select an item the text changes to that item selected.

so a drop down list with a fixed header.
Is there a better way to do this?
Does anyone know how to make a combo box with a fixed header ?

Comment: IsEditable="True" and you wonder why you get a TestEdit cursor

Comment: i dont think you read it all. i would like the list to have the text in the header of the column, when you click the column the drop down appears. when the users clicks the item in the drop down. the text doesnt change

Answer (score 0):

So i didnt get an answer, but i figured it out.

```
<Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader" >
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DockPanel>
                            <Grid>
                                <ComboBox Background="Transparent" Foreground="Black" BorderBrush="Transparent" MaxDropDownHeight="8000"
                                          Name="ComboBox_DataQuery_SelectedItem"
                                          MinWidth="120" DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                          SelectedItem="{Binding Filter_ListView_DataQuery}" 
                                          SelectedIndex="{Binding FilterIndex_ListView_DataQuery}" 
                                          Drop="ComboBox_GridView_Filter_DropDownClosed"
                                          DropDownOpened="ComboBox_GridView_Filter_DropDownOpen" Uid="{Binding}"
                                          />
                                <Label Margin="0,0,20,0" DockPanel.Dock="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" 
                                       Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" IsHitTestVisible="False"  Focusable="False"
                                       Content="{Binding}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>



        <ListView DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="ListView_DataQuery" ItemsSource="{Binding ListView_DataQuery}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>

                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="ComputerName" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ComputerName}" Header="Computer Name"></GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Header="Property Name"></GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="Type" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Type}" Header="Property Type"></GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="Value" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}" Header="Property Value"></GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="Instance" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RelPath}" Header="Instance"></GridViewColumn>

                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

all that didnt work well was when you clicked an item for filtering, i just had to set the combo box's Selected Index back to -1